# Edit HTTP POST method to POST different data depending on existing data in .NET Core

Tags: http, .net-core

I'm creating an API for a game that can (for now) only be played over Postman issuing POST and GET requests. It needs to be able to receive POST requests and update the InMemory database based on previous requests. Player state is not an issue - it just needs to allow for a player to issue a request and update a value based on the value of the previous request.

I have a Model that contains the class variables and  automatically sets one of the variables to a PlayerScore value (0, initially).

```
        public class Game
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public long PlayerScore { get; set; }
            public bool Roll { get; set; }
            public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
            public Game()
            {
                this.PlayerScore = 0;
            }
        }
```

This sets the score to 0 every time the game is played/HTTP POST requests are submitted, but I want to be able to edit this value based on previous turns in the game.

Where should I place this method?

The POST is performed via an 'ActionResult' style method.

Thanks for any help anyone can possibly provide!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using your `Game` class for both your internal game state and also the model from the POST request.

I'd recommend creating a separate class for your POST request so that they don't get confused. e.g.

```cs
public class GameUpdateRequest
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long PlayerScore { get; set; }
    public bool Roll { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}

// .. controller action
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateGame([FromBody] GameUpdateRequest request)
{
    if (request.PlayerScore > 0)
        // update game state logic
}
```

Then your request model can change and is not tied to the game state model. You could make PlayerScore nullable in the request or add other properties.